# Formularios en Ionic

Tags: angularjs, ionic

** Ionic**

---

Estoy desarrollando una app de asistencias para mi escuela, una de las paginas, tiene un botón para agregar, yo quiero que al pulsar el botón, este me lleve a un formulario, en donde se pueda poner el nombre y apellido, y cuando hagan click en el boton que diga "enviar", este me lleve a la pagina que tiene el boton de agregar +,y agregue el nombre y el apellido en forma de tarjeta.

[image]

Comment: y no tienes código?

Answer (score 1):

Puedes hacerlo con un modal:[ModalController](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/modal/ModalController/), [ModalComponent](https://ionicframework.com/docs/components/#modals)

En el modal debes cargar el formulario (puede ser otra página), y luego al grabar el formulario puedes devolver algún valor o variable. Desde la página donde tienes el +, escuchas el evento **onDidDismiss** del modal, y así puedes obtener la respuesta: Ej:

home.ts

```
...
public mostrarFormularioModal() {
  let formularioModal = this.modalCtrl.create(formularioPage);
  formularioModal.onDidDismiss(respuesta => {
    if(respuesta) {
      mostrarDatosEnTarjetas();
    }
  });
  formularioModal.present();
}

public mostrarDatosEnTarjetas() {
   //mostrar los datos en tarjetas
}
...
```

---

formulario-page.ts

```
...
public grabarFormulario() {
  //grabar los datos del formulario
  this.viewCtrl.dismiss(true);
}
...
```

Ionic tiene muy buena documentación, deberías echarle un ojo.

Comment: Gracias, Lee abajo

Answer (score 0):

// Formulario

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';


@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-añadir11',
  templateUrl: 'añadir11.html',
})
export class Añadir11Page {

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams) {
  }

  ionViewDidLoad() {
    console.log('ionViewDidLoad Añadir11Page');
  }


}
```

//Pagina con el boton +

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';
import { Añadir11Page } from "../añadir11/añadir11";



@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-manana11',
  templateUrl: 'manana11.html',
})
export class Manana11Page {

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams,) {
  }

  ionViewDidLoad() {
    console.log('ionViewDidLoad Manana11Page');
  }

subir(){
  this.navCtrl.push( Añadir11Page );

}


}
```

Comment: ¿Qué es esto? Una respuesta a tu propia pregunta, o más infrmación que estás agregando, que en realidad deberías haber **[editado](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/144960/edit) en tu pregunta**. Código sin ninguna descripción como este puede terminar siendo eliminado.